# not <| doesn't work for linq2sql?

Tags: linq-to-sql, f#

```
<@[for i in linq.TrueIncidents -> i.RecTime, i.Name, (if i.Description = null && i.ID.HasValue = false then i.Message else "hello") ] @>
```

works

```
<@[for i in linq.TrueIncidents -> i.RecTime, i.Name, (if i.Description = null && not <| i.ID.HasValue then i.Message else "hello") ] @>
```

doesn't work

does "not" works inside linq2sql ? or is it a bug ?

Comment: What happens if you use `not i.ID.HasValue` instead of `not <| i.ID.HasValue`?

Comment: @kvb yes, without <| it works well , so that must be just because of '<|' usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a known limitation of the F# quotations to LINQ translator. As far as I know, the translator leaves sub-expressions as you write them (e.g. condition in `if .. then` or the expression following `yield ..`), so you can only use constructs that C# understands.

The only place where pipelining is handled is when you write:

```
<@ source |> Seq.filter (...) |> Seq.etc (...) @>
```

You can see that in the source code - search for `CallPipe` in [LinqQueries.fs](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/54799#685009). This is definitely a bit unfortunate, because both `|>` and `<|` could be handled just by replacing them with their definition (which is fairly simple). I believe this will be improved in the next F# release, so you can send email to *fsbugs* at *microsoft* dot *com* to make sure this bug doesn't get lost.

Comment: Good. Head is last (current) sources ?

Comment: @Bjorky: Yes, head is the latest (publicly available) version.